# How to inject a x86 dll into a 32bits process

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, dll-injection

I have a `qt` gui build as a DLL when compiled as `x64` it works correctly, however, when I compile it as x86 and inject it into a 32bits process, its DllMain entry never gets called.

After a lot of time searching and recompiling the qt source I figured out it `maybe` is not a problem with `qt` because I have been able to reproduce the issue with a "clean" "non-qt" dll project:

`source`

```
#include <Windows.h>
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    OutputDebugString(L"DllMain");
    return TRUE;
}
```

And this is how I'm `injecting` the dll:

```
void injectDLL(DWORD processID, const QString& dllPath)
{
    // Open the target process.
    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    if (!processHandle)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open process";
        return;
    }

    // Allocate memory in the target process.
    LPVOID remoteMemory = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, NULL, dllPath.length(), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!remoteMemory)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to allocate memory in the remote process";
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    // Write the path of the DLL to be injected into the allocated memory in the target process.
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, remoteMemory, dllPath.toStdWString().c_str(), dllPath.length() * sizeof(wchar_t), NULL))
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to write path to the remote process memory";
        VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, remoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    // Get the address of the LoadLibraryW function.
    LPVOID loadLibraryAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");
    if (!loadLibraryAddress)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to get the address of LoadLibraryW";
        VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, remoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    // Create a remote thread in the target process and pass the address of LoadLibraryW and the address of the allocated memory as arguments.
    HANDLE remoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(processHandle, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loadLibraryAddress, remoteMemory, 0, NULL);
    if (!remoteThread)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to create a remote thread in the target process";
        VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, remoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    // Wait for the remote thread to finish.
    WaitForSingleObject(remoteThread, INFINITE);

    // Cleanup.
    CloseHandle(remoteThread);
    VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, remoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(processHandle);
}


int main()
{
    // wmplayer.exe pid
    injectDLL(51836, "D:/repos/Dll/Debug/Dll.dll");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm `testing` injecting the dll into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe` which is an x32 exe.

I'm debugging the dll on vs22 but after injected it never gets called, and neither the `OutputDebugString(L"DllMain");` is printed.

I'm trying to fix the problem on my qt dll, which probably is the same as the sample I provided above.

What I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Is your "injector" also compiled as 32bit when trying to inject into the 32bit process?

Comment: and on Windows, a path should use \ instead of /.

Comment: @LouisBernard Backslash or forward slash in paths are mostly interchangeable on Windows. The filename in this case is unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: of course you must allocate not `dllPath.length()` but `(1 + dllPath.length()) * sizeof(wchar_t)` and copy such size. but if your `length < 0x800` this not lead to error. but main - why you not attach debugger to target process and not set bp on `LoadLibraryW` ?

Comment: @LouisBernard no, the "injectDLL" function was being called from a project compiled as x64, i compiled it now as x86 but it still not calling the dll entry. I also tried modifying the path.

Comment: @RbMm i dont understand what you mean? the target process is just that dll source

Comment: @Daniel You rely on the fact that the address of LoadLibrary is the same in all processes. This is generally true, but if your target process is a WOW process (32 bit) you need to start your remote thread on the LoadLibrary address of the WOW kernel32.dll. You cannot rely on GetProcAddress here to find the start location of your remote thread. The WOW LoadLibrary in the remote process is somewhere else.

Comment: Basically your GetProcAddress call will return the pointer to the 64 bit LoadLibrary (if your injector is x64), but you need to start your remote thread at the 32 bit LoadLibrary (if your target process is 32 bit)

Comment: @LouisBernard i see, is it possible to make the injector also work to inject on x32 when its running on x64 process?

Comment: Sure, but you need to find another way to get the LoadLibrary address in your target process (maybe walk 32 bit PEB in remote process...).

Comment: @LouisBernard do you have any example or code?

Comment: No, sorry. Should be fairly simple to implement though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the process id that is passed into the `injectDll()` method is correct? I suggest implementing the following method and declaring it like this.

```cpp
int findProcess(const char* processName) {
    HANDLE handle
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    int pid = 0;
    BOOL result;

    handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return pid;

    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    result = Process32First(handle, &pe);
    while (result) {
        if (strcmp(processName, pe.szExeFile) == 0) {
            pid = pe.th32ProcessId;
            break;
        }
        result = Process32Next(handle, &pe);
    }

    CloseHandle(handle);
    return pid;
}

void injectDLL(DWORD processID, const QString& dllPath)
{
    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    if (!processHandle)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open process";
        return;
    }

    LPVOID remoteMemory = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, NULL,
        dllPath.length(), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!remoteMemory)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to allocate memory in the remote process";
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, remoteMemory, 
        dllPath.toStdWString().c_str(), dllPath.length() * sizeof(wchar_t), NULL))
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to write path to the remote process memory";
        VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, remoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    LPVOID loadLibraryAddress = 
        GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");
    if (!loadLibraryAddress)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to get the address of LoadLibraryW";
        VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, remoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    
    HANDLE remoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(processHandle, NULL, 0, 
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loadLibraryAddress, remoteMemory, 0, NULL);
    if (!remoteThread)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to create a remote thread in the target process";
        VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, remoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(processHandle);
        return;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(remoteThread, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(remoteThread);
    VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, remoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(processHandle);
}

int main()
{
    injectDLL(findProcess("wmplayer.exe"), "D:/repos/Dll/Debug/Dll.dll");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i have verified the pid is correct, i also tried with your version, the entry is not getting called;